# Why does the default initialization of the elements of an array<T*, N> require C++14?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++14

Consider the following MWE (https://godbolt.org/g/aydjpW):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
template<size_t N> constexpr std::array<void*, N> empty_array{};
```

My goal is to have an array of size `N` where every element is default-initialized (in the case of this MWE, a `nullptr`). g++ 5.4.0 with `-std=c++11` complains that

> variable templates only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14

I don't understand why. According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array, `array<T, N>` exists since C++11 and the implicitly declared constructor

> initializes the array following the rules of aggregate initialization

Following the link to the description of aggregate initialization at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization, it says that

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of
>   members or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members
>   are value-initialized.

Thus, my assumption would have been that my code above is valid C++11. What am I missing here that variable templates get involved somehow, which would require C++14?

Comment: You aren't declaring an *array*, you are declaring a variable template

Comment: I think your confusion comes from the meaning of the word _variable_. The word _variable_ in the error message does NOT refer to _variable number of template arguments_. It refers to the (global) variable `empty_array`, because you cannot use `template <...>` in front of a variable (before C++14).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To declare an `array` of 5 elements:

```
constexpr std::array<void*, 5> empty_array{};
```

To declare an `array` of 10 elements:

```
constexpr std::array<void*, 10> empty_array{};
```

To declare an array of N elements where N is not fixed, you need to use a template which can be instantiated for different values of N:

```
// A variable of type std::array<void*, N> where N is not fixed yet:
template<size_t N> constexpr std::array<void*, N> empty_array{};

// Then given a function like this:
void do_something(const std::array<void*, 5>&);

// You use the variable like this, by giving the value of N:
void some_function() {
  do_something(empty_array<5>);
}
```

But this is a *variable template* which is a new feature in C++14. You can't do this in C++11, so you get that compiler error.

Either use C++14, or do something like:

```
// An alias template defining a _type_ of array with no fixed N:
template<std::size_t N>
  using voidptr_array = std::array<void*, N>;

constexpr voidptr_array<5> empty_array_of_5{};
constexpr voidptr_array<10> empty_array_of_10{};

void do_something(const std::array<void*, 5>&);

void some_function() {
  do_something(empty_array_of_5);
}
```

This alias template defines a *type* that takes N as a parameter, instead of a *variable* that takes N as a parameter. You still need to define variables of that type, like `empty_array_of_5` and `empty_array_of_10`.

Answer (score 9):

Variable templates have been introduced in C++14, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template

Comment: Yes, but where in my code is there a variable template?

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger `template<size_t N> constexpr std::array<void*, N> empty_array{};` is a variable template.

Comment: @Holt: But there is only one template parameter (`N`) and not a variably long list of them.

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger: maybe you wanted: `constexpr std::array<void*, 42> empty_array{};` instead. Currently, your `N` is not fixed, but a template parameter.

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger - you aren't declating **a** variable; you're declaring a set of variables; one for every `N`

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger A variable template is a variable which is templated, you are confusing variable template and [variadic template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template).

Comment: @max66: I am aware of that. I wrote this template so that I don't have to copy-paste my declarations for changing values of N.

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger - good; what you've done is defined as "variable template" and is available starting from C++14.

Comment: @Holt: I see. Thanks. I was indeed confusing the two. Thank you for pointing this out.